# Function not found in scope of main

Tags: c++, scope

I have a problem, normally I would understand why this is happening, I didnt declare the function in the main method.  But the class itself includes the .h file, which has the prototype for this method, so I am a bit lost on why it is not in the scope of the main function.

```
  using namespace std;
  #include "Solar.h"


int main(){
  initializeGL();
  Stars *Alpha = new Stars(5.0);
  Planets *Awe = new Planets(.6,2,30,"Awe",0.0,0.0,0.0);
  paintGL();
  return 0;
}

void Solar::initializeGL(){

  glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  glClearDepth(1.0f);

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

  glHint(GL_PERSPECTIV
  ....
 }
```

There is also a function paintGL() later on, and here is the header file

```
 class Solar {
 public:
  void initializeGL();
  void resizeGL(int width, int height);
  void paintGL();
  .....
private:
  .....
};
```

I am not the best with c++, so anyhelp will be appreciated.

ANd here is the error

```
Solar.cpp:4: error: declaration of âvoid Solar::initializeGL()â outside of class is not definition
Solar.cpp:5: error: declaration of âvoid Solar::paintGL()â outside of class is not definition
Solar.cpp: In function âint main()â:
Solar.cpp:8: error: âinitializeGLâ was not declared in this scope
Solar.cpp:11: error: âpaintGLâ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: What's the error message, and which function is it complaining about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Solar` is a class, and `initializeGL` and `paintGL` are member functions. If you wanted to use them, you would have to create an instance of `Solar`.

```
Solar solar;
solar.initializeGL();
// ...more
solar.paintGL();
```

Read up on member functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk812w4w.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The `paintGL()` function is a member function of the class `Solar`.  You can only call it on an object of type `Solar`:

```
Solar s;
s.paintGL();
```

If you want to be able to call it without object, you should either make it a free function, or a static member function:

```
// free
void paintGL();

// static member
class Solar {
public: static void paintGL();
};
```

This of course only works if `paintGL` uses no member data of `Solar`...

Answer (score 2):

Both functions are instance functions; you need to instantiate a new Solar object and call the functions from it, not out of scope like you did

Answer (score 1):

`initializeGL` and `paintGL` are both member functions of the `Solar` class, but you're trying to call them like they are global functions.  That won't work.

You either need an instance of `Solar`:

```
int main(){
  Solar* solar = ... // magic

  solar->initializeGL();
  Stars *Alpha = new Stars(5.0);
  Planets *Awe = new Planets(.6,2,30,"Awe",0.0,0.0,0.0);
  solar->paintGL();
```

...or make the functions static member functions:

```
class Solar {
 public:
  static void initializeGL();
  void resizeGL(int width, int height);
  static void paintGL();
  .....
private:
  .....
};
```

...or (worst option by far), make them global functions.